# How to assign class to innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, function, class, innerhtml

I have a form and I want to print result when I click on the button. I know how to assign to innerHTML a result of basic function but what if I have a class?

I have something like this:

```
    Weight: <input type="number" id="weight" /><br/> Height: <input type="number" id="height" /><br/>

    <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>

    <span id="result"></span>
```

```
    class SomeClass {
        constructor() {
            this.number = 0;
            this.weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
            this.height = document.getElementById('height').value;
        }

        FirstMethod() {
            if (this.weight < 10) {
                this.number += 1;
                return this.number;
            }
        }

        SecondMethod() {
            if (this.height < 10) {
                this.number += 2;
                return this.number;
            }
        }
    }
```

and on the top:

```
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', result);

    function result() {
        let overall = new SomeClass().FirstMethod().SecondMethod().number;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = overall;
    }
```

I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).FirstMethod(...).SecondMethod is not a function". I tried to do it in many different ways and nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not chain the call of new. You need to store it as an instance in a variable first.

```
 function result() {
        let overall = new SomeClass();
        overall = overall.FirstMethod().SecondMethod().number;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = overall;
    }
```

But better practice is make it immutable like this:

```
 function result() {
        let overallInstance = new SomeClass();
        let overall = overallInstance.FirstMethod().SecondMethod().number;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = overall;
    }
```

Also I notice, you return a value in FirstMethod(). This must return the instance itself to allow chainable calls.

Comment: I also don't know why someone downvoted, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **FirstMethod().SecondMethod()**

try to use

```
let my_object = new SomeClass();
my_object.FirstMethod();
my_object.SecondMethod();

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = my_object.number
```